# How to fill plot symbols with hatching in R?

Tags: r, plot

When plotting points in R, some of the points are supposed to be filled with a hatching. For these I use the plot symbols `pch={21:25}`, which can be filled.

So far I tried using the `bg` parameter, also as `pt.bg` in combination with `density`, but it seems like it does not work for plot symbols.

I am not sure if that is relevant, but the code is compiled using `knitr`.

I am looking for a way to fill the plot symbols with different hatchings, or for an alternative to differentiate between symbols of the same size and shape without using other colors than black and white.